# Asynchronous UI updates in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

I'd like to achieve similar effect in textbox in windows forms as you have in the output window in visual studio  - that means while it's printing some stuff, you can actually scroll down up and down freely.

Unfortunatelly my attempts with async / await continue to be unsuccessfull (I'm blocking the UI ).

So far I got this :

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            richTextBox1.Text = "";
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                await ProcessFile(openFileDialog1.FileNames.First());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception gg)
        {
            SupportingClass.SaveError(gg);
        }
    }
//simplified
private async Task ProcessFilecsv(string path)
{
     IEnumerable<T> products = GetProducts<T>(path);
     foreach (var item in products)
     {
         string select = @"select something from datatable";
         List<object[]> result = await  Support.Overall.RetrieveSelectDataAsync(select);

         richTextBox1.AppendText(int.Parse(result[0][0].ToString()) > 0 ? "Added" : "Not found"));
     }
}
```

I also tried to use `Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> dosth().ContinureWith(x => /* appending to richboxtext1 */ )` but also without success.

What am I missing?

Comment: Pause the debugger while it's frozen and see where it's stuck.

Comment: Ui is single thread, you may perform some expansive operation in another thread but to update controls you must dispatch to ui thread using BeginInvoke. Search an example for that or for backgroundworker

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    await ProcessFile(openFileDialog1.FileNames.First());
    ...
}

private async Task ProcessFile(string path) 
{
    return Task.StartNew(() => { 
        IEnumerable<T> products = GetProducts<T>(path);
        foreach (var item in products)
        {
            string select = @"select something from datatable";
            List<object[]> result = await  Support.Overall.RetrieveSelectDataAsync(select);

            // i'm using a little helper method here...
            Do(richTextBox1, rb => rb.AppendText(int.Parse...);
        }
    });
}

public static void Do<TControl>(TControl control, Action<TControl> action) where TControl : Control
{
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
    {
        control.Invoke(action, control);
    }
    else
    {
        action(control);
    }
}
```